# Using ScrollView with StackView as subview and UIViews as children of StackView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm struggling to get my scroll view to work programatically.

I have a view controller that instantiates a UIScrollView with the following constraints

```
class HomeTabBarController: ViewController {
  let homePageView = HomePageView()

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    homePageView.setupHomePage()
    view.addSubview(homePageView)
    
    ///constraints
    homePageView.stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    homePageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    homePageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true;
    homePageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true;
    homePageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -83).isActive = true;
  }
}
```

The HomePageView (UIScrollView) has a UIStackView and instantiates 3 more UIViews which are the UIStackView's children. The code and constraints are as follows

```
class HomePageView: UIScrollView {
var homePageCarrousel: HomePageCarrousel?
var homePageSocial: HomePageSocialUp?
var homePageAboutUs: HomePageAboutUs?
var stackView = UIStackView()

func setupHomePage() {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    homePageCarrousel = HomePageCarrousel()
    homePageSocial = HomePageSocialUp()
    homePageAboutUs = HomePageAboutUs()

    guard let homePageSocial = homePageSocial, let homePageCarrousel = homePageCarrousel, let homePageAboutUs = homePageAboutUs else { return }

    homePageSocial.setupSocialHeader()
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(homePageSocial)

    homePageCarrousel.setupCarrousel()
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(homePageCarrousel)

    homePageAboutUs.setup()
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(homePageAboutUs)

    addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 10

    setLayout()
}

func setLayout(){
    guard let homePageSocial = homePageSocial, let homePageCarrousel = homePageCarrousel, let homePageAboutUs = homePageAboutUs else { return }

    ///header
    homePageSocial.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    homePageSocial.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    homePageSocial.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    ///carrousel
    homePageCarrousel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    homePageCarrousel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    homePageCarrousel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

    ///about us
    homePageAboutUs.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    homePageAboutUs.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: homePageCarrousel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    homePageAboutUs.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    homePageAboutUs.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    ///stackview
    self.stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true;
    self.stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true;
    self.stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true;
    self.stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
}

func dispose() {
    homePageSocial = nil
    homePageCarrousel = nil
    homePageAboutUs = nil
    subviews.forEach{$0.removeFromSuperview()}
}
}
```

Each of the children UIView (homePageSocial, homePageCarrousel and homePageAboutUs) have constraints have also got constraints:

**HomePageCarrousel**

Loads UIImageView and after adding as subview sets the constraint as

```
heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageView.frame.height).isActive = true
```

**HomePageAboutUs**
Has 3 UITextviews (headerText, bodyTextLeft, bodyTextRight)
Header on top, bodytextLeft below it being 50% width of screen x = 0 and bodyTextRight x = width of bodyTextLeft.

Constraints are as follows

```
heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: headerText.frame.height + bodyTextLeft.frame.height).isActive = true
    
    bodyTextLeft.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerText.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    bodyTextLeft.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2).isActive = true
    bodyTextRight.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerText.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    bodyTextRight.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2).isActive = true
    bodyTextRight.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyTextLeft.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

**HomePageSocialUp**
A basic header with an icon and a constraint of

```
heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 325).isActive = true
```

After all that set I still can't get my ui scroll view to scroll on the y axis leaving my text of homePageAboutUs below the tabBar and off screen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're doing a lot of things wrong... first question though: you say *"HomePageAboutUs Has 3 UITextviews (headerText, bodyTextLeft, bodyTextRight)"* -- do you need text views because the user can edit them? or so they can scroll? or should they really be multi-line labels?

Comment: I guess you are right. They are only meant to show text and not for user interaction. The only thing I want to scroll is the screen since the text is off screen in the Y axis. The content on the scroll view is bigger than the screen height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - the main purpose of a `UIStackView` is to *arrange its subviews*, so it is wrong to add position constraints to those subviews.

Next, when adding subviews to the "root" view of a controller (such as your scroll view), be sure to constrain them to the Safe Area Layout Guide.

Third, constrain the content of your scroll view to its Content Layout Guide.

I'm kind of taking your descriptions and hoping I'm close to what you're going for here:

[image]

and after scrolling down:

[image]

Here is your code, modified to produce that result:

```
class HomeTabBarController: UIViewController {
    
    let homePageView = HomePageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        homePageView.setupHomePage()
        view.addSubview(homePageView)

        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        ///constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            homePageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            homePageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            homePageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            homePageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }

}

class HomePageSocialUp: UIView {
    func setupSocialHeader() -> Void {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = .red
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imgView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain image view 20-pts on each side
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // Height = 325
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 325.0),
        ])
        if let img = UIImage(named: "myHeaderImage") {
            imgView.image = img
        }
    }
}
class HomePageCarrousel: UIView {
    func setupCarrousel() -> Void {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = .green
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imgView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain image view 20-pts on each side
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // let's make it 3:2 ratio
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2.0 / 3.0)
        ])
        if let img = UIImage(named: "myCarouselImage") {
            imgView.image = img
        }
    }
}
class HomePageAboutUs: UIView {
    let headerText = UILabel()
    let bodyTextLeft = UILabel()
    let bodyTextRight = UILabel()
    
    func setup() -> Void {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = .blue
        
        [headerText, bodyTextLeft, bodyTextRight].forEach {
            // keep label height to text content
            $0.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            $0.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            // allow word-wrap
            $0.numberOfLines = 0
            // yellow background
            $0.backgroundColor = .yellow
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview($0)
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // header text 8-pts from Top / Leading / Trailing
            headerText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            headerText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            headerText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            // left text 8-pts from Bottom of header text, 8-pts Leading
            bodyTextLeft.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerText.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            bodyTextLeft.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            
            // right text 8-pts from Bottom of header text, 8-pts Trailing
            bodyTextRight.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerText.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            bodyTextRight.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            // 8-pts between left and right text
            bodyTextRight.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyTextLeft.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            
            // left and right text equal width
            bodyTextLeft.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyTextRight.widthAnchor),
            
            // constrain Bottom of both to <= 8 (at least 8-pts
            bodyTextLeft.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            bodyTextRight.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])

        headerText.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .regular)
        bodyTextLeft.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
        bodyTextRight.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)

        // texxt alignment
        headerText.textAlignment = .center
        bodyTextLeft.textAlignment = .left
        bodyTextRight.textAlignment = .right
        
        // some sample text
        headerText.text = "This is the text for the About Us Header label. It will, of course, wrap onto multiple lines when needed, and auto-size it's height to fit the text."
        bodyTextLeft.text = "Left label with\nembedded newlines\nso we can see it grow\nto fit the text.\nLine 5\nLine 6\nLine 7"
        bodyTextRight.text = "Right label will wrap if needed. The one with the most lines will determine the bottom."
    }
}

class HomePageView: UIScrollView {
    var homePageCarrousel: HomePageCarrousel?
    var homePageSocial: HomePageSocialUp?
    var homePageAboutUs: HomePageAboutUs?
    var stackView = UIStackView()
    
    func setupHomePage() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        homePageCarrousel = HomePageCarrousel()
        homePageSocial = HomePageSocialUp()
        homePageAboutUs = HomePageAboutUs()
        
        guard let homePageSocial = homePageSocial, let homePageCarrousel = homePageCarrousel, let homePageAboutUs = homePageAboutUs else { return }
        
        homePageSocial.setupSocialHeader()
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(homePageSocial)
        
        homePageCarrousel.setupCarrousel()
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(homePageCarrousel)
        
        homePageAboutUs.setup()
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(homePageAboutUs)
        
        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 10
        
        setLayout()
    }
    
    func setLayout(){
        
        // constrain stackView to scroll view's Content Layout Guide
        let g = self.contentLayoutGuide
        
        ///stackview
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            self.stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            self.stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            self.stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
            // stack view width is scroll view's frame layout guide width
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on and thanks for such good comments throughout the code. It makes it crystal clear and makes me realise my own mistakes